# How to Use cy.fixture along with Array when multiple records in JSON fixture file

Tags: cypress

\Created a Cypress Testscript  in and set for execution in loop as would like to execute with multiple set of testdata in fixture json.if you down and see the cy.fixture is works only for first entry and test executed twice with fisrt entry in json (testdata file ) .anyhelp on how to include Iteration of array along with fixture would be helpful

```
var Launchindex = 0;
for (Launchindex = 0; Launchindex  < 2; Launchindex ++) {

describe('Launch  testsite',() => {

    it('try login using testdata', () => {

        cy.visit('https://xyzz')
        cy.title().should('contain','title check')
    })

    it('check url', () => {

        cy.url().should('contain','xyz')

    })

    it('enter details and submit', () => { 
        //Fixture loads the testdata setup in fixtures folder , so setup testdata required before executing test script   



        cy.fixture('testdata').then(testdata  => {

            const ModuleID = testdata[0].ModuleID 
            const LoginName = testdata[0].LoginName
            const gameid = testdata[0].gameid

        cy.get('#ModuleID').type(ModuleID)
        cy.get('#LoginName').type(LoginName)
        cy.get('#gameid').type(gameid)
        cy.get('#btnSubmit').click()

        })
    })

})

}

fixture file looks somethings like this 
[
{"id": 0,"ModuleID": "xxxx","LoginName": "xxxx","gameid": "xxxx"},
{"id": 1,"ModuleID": "yyy","LoginName": "yyy","gameid": "yyyy"}
]
```

Answer (score 7):

`cy.fixture('testdata')` will be evaluated when Cypress executes it, so a loop in the top level of a module won't work.

You can do this instead:

```js
describe('Launch testsite', () => {
    it('enter details and submit', () => {
        cy.fixture('testdata').then(testdata => {
            testdata.forEach(data => {
                const ModuleID = data.ModuleID;
                const LoginName = data.LoginName;
                const gameid = data.gameid;

                cy.get('#ModuleID').type(ModuleID);
                cy.get('#LoginName').type(LoginName);
                cy.get('#gameid').type(gameid);
                cy.get('#btnSubmit').click();

                // in a real test you probably need to do some kind of assertion here
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @miklos_me but still unable to read the second entry from JSON

Comment: @CypressAuto Do you want to generate separate test cases for each entry in that fixture?

Comment: prefer to have single test and able to read  entries from json/any another format   one after another and execute ..any suggestions how to make it work

Comment: forEach() works me instead of using cy.fixture  .. const testData = require("../fixtures/testdata.json");

Comment: This does work ! Thankyou so much ! Declared following before describe : `const testData = require("../../fixtures/multipleInputFields.json")`
and then `testData.forEach((data) => {  const message = data.message
it('Test Case1', function(){     
cy.log("data is:" + data)
cy.get('#user-message').type(message).should('have.value', message)
cy.get('#get-input > button').click()
 cy.wait(200)
 cy.get('span#display').should('have.text', message)
     }) });`

Comment: Refer Cypress official Recipe for the same task: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/fundamentals__fixtures/cypress/e2e/list-spec.cy.js