# How to read the fixture JSON file in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, json, cypress, fixtures

I want to read data from a JSON fixture file in Cypress in my test cases.

For whatever reason it does not work. I followed several instructions and examples and simply do not make it work. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my files and code snippets.

TEST CASE:

```
describe('Test for user data via JSON', ()=> {

 
    // Use the cy.fixture() method to pull data from fixture file
    before(function () {
        cy.fixture('users').then(function (userData) {
            this.userData = userData;
            })
        })

    it.only('Login Test. User1', () => {
        
        cy.wait(500)
        cy.visit('http://localhost/')

        cy.wait(500)

        onLoginPage.usernameInput(this.userData[0].username)
        onLoginPage.passwordInput(this.userData[0].password)
        onLoginPage.buttonGo()

    })
})
```

JSON FILE

file name: users.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "username": "User1",
        "password": "password1",
        "_comment": "All rights"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "User2",
        "password": "password2",
        "_comment": "All rights"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "User3",
        "password": "password3",
        "_comment": "Reading only"
    }
]
```

The error message is:
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'users')"
The error message marks the "u" oder "userData" from this:

```
onLoginPage.usernameInput(this.**u**serData[0].username)
```

The fixture folder is hierarchically here:
"../fixtures/users"

The examples that I have seen look so simple. No idea what am I missing here.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution via this post:

[How to Use cy.fixture along with Array when multiple records in JSON fixture file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593100/how-to-use-cy-fixture-along-with-array-when-multiple-records-in-json-fixture-fil)

I meant this part:

```
cy.fixture('testdata').then(testdata  => {

            const ModuleID = testdata[0].ModuleID 
            const LoginName = testdata[0].LoginName
            const gameid = testdata[0].gameid

        cy.get('#ModuleID').type(ModuleID)
        cy.get('#LoginName').type(LoginName)
        cy.get('#gameid').type(gameid)
        cy.get('#btnSubmit').click()
```

This way I can read from my .json file.

I did not do the beforeEach, I can work with this inside the test case.

Thanx for everybody helping me.

Case closed with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are only ever going to write one test, do not use `this` context to access fixture data.

[**Test Isolation**](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation) will clear that data to ensure one test does not pollute the scope of the next test.

If you are only going to use `userData` for the login test, simplify by using `cy.fixture()` inside that test.

```js
it('Login Test. User1', function() {
  cy.fixture('users').then(data => {

    userData = data.find(d => d.username === 'User1')

    cy.visit('/')
    onLoginPage.usernameInput(userData.username)
    onLoginPage.passwordInput(userData.password)
    onLoginPage.buttonGo()
  })
})
```

Comment: Wouldn´t this be easier in this case? `onLoginPage.usernameInput('User1')` . In that case I do not need to read from that fixture .json file but I want to read from the .json file. Or I do not understand what you showed me.

Comment: Sure, you can do that. But where are you getting password from? That has to be read from data. It's a minor detail - the important thing to note is you cannot always use `this` scope to store data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an arrow function inside `then()`, as you do inside `only()` later on. Scoping works differently between arrow functions and 'regular' anonymous functions, meaning `this` inside that function refers to a different scope. So you're likely setting the `userData` property on a different object than the one you're accessing later on.

Note: I'm assuming your error message refers to `this.userData`, not `this.users`, since you never actually read this property in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor arrow functions:
Replace the arrow functions with regular functions for the describe, before, and it blocks:

```
describe('Test for user data via JSON', function() {

before(function() {
    cy.fixture('users').then(function(userData) {
        this.userData = userData;
    });
});

it.only('Login Test. User1', function() {
    cy.wait(500);
    cy.visit('http://localhost/');

    cy.wait(500);

    onLoginPage.usernameInput(this.userData[0].username);
    onLoginPage.passwordInput(this.userData[0].password);
    onLoginPage.buttonGo();
});
});
```

Accessing fixtures:
Your current code seems correct. Just ensure that the users.json file is directly inside the fixtures folder.

Custom commands:
Ensure that the custom commands (onLoginPage.usernameInput, etc.) are correctly defined in your commands.js file and that you've imported them correctly.

Comment: My imports: In test case file: `import { onLoginPage } from "../support/page_objects/loginPage"`. The loginPage file itself, for instance: 
    `usernameInput(userInput){
        cy.get('#loginname').type(userInput)
    }` .